# How to show dialog on top of the frame, even if setAlwaysOnTop() is set in Java?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, frame

If the frame have set setAlwaysOnTop() and some dialog is running the dialog is showing underneath the frame. I want to show it on top of the frame. I other words - the dialog should still be on top of the frame, even if setAlwaysOnTop() is set.

Can somebody help me with this?

EDIT:

It's example code:

```
public MainFrame() {
        super("Potatator");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "I want to set this dialog on top of frame");
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: what about using anothe layout? e.g. GridBagLayout etc?

Comment: Does the dialog have the frame as a parent? Without testing, I would assume modal dialogues would always be on top of their parents..

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, comipable, before anything here to read Oracle tutorial about How to Use Modality in Dialogs as the part in Using Other Swing Features

Comment: @Zorlan what is connection between layouts and setAlwaysOnTop() method?

Comment: @Duncan yes, the dialog have the frame as parents like in exaple which i added to my post. I though like you but it doesn't work.

Comment: When I run your code, the Dialog is on top of the MainFrame?!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for this problem is settings `setAlwaysOnTop` temporary to false while the dialog is shown, then set it to true when the dialog is closed.

```java
setAlwaysOnTop(false);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "I want to set this dialog on top of frame");
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. It was solved by calling passing frame as owner of the dialog:

```
public SettingsDialog(Window owner) {
        super(owner);
```